# css ::part pseudo selector Chrome compatibility?

Tags: css, web-component, lit

I have recently been learning about custom elements and Lit js. I am trying to style my components with the [`::part`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::part) pseudo-selector.

This works in Firefox, but it seems not to work in Chrome.

As far as I can tell this should be supported in both. I have been able to replicate the issue in a code pen (linked below).

Should I expect this code to render a red square in Chrome?

```js
import * as lit from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lit@2.5.0";

class TTest extends lit.LitElement {
  static styles =  lit.css`
    ::part(test) {
      display: block;
      color: red;
      background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  `
  
  render() {
    return lit.html`
      <div part="test">
      
      </div>
    `
  }
}

customElements.define('t-test', TTest);
```

Firefox version: `108.0.1 (64-bit)`

Chrome version: `108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

OS: `Arch Linux x86_64 6.1.1-arch1-1`

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/deereb/pen/YzjqdYM)
|
[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3Apart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you found a bug

> ::part, a set of pseudo-elements that allow you to style inside a shadow tree,
> **from outside** of that shadow tree.

FireFox seems to allow styling from **inside** the shadowTree itself

This Native Code has different output in Browsers:

```html
<style>
    wc-container ::part(redpart) {
      color: yellow;
      background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<wc-container>
  <wc-part-test> red part </wc-part-test>
</wc-container>

<wc-part-test> NOT red part </wc-part-test>

<script>
  customElements.define('wc-container', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
     super().attachShadow({mode:"open"}).innerHTML=`<slot/>`;
  }});
  customElements.define('wc-part-test', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
     super()
      .attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = 
        `<style>::part(redpart){ font:2em Arial }</style>` + 
        `Hello <span part="redpart"><slot></slot></span> Web Component`;
  }});
</script>
```

### Firefox

[image]

Because the `<style>` is inside the shadowRoot, the `font` styling *can* be done **without** `::part`

### Chromium

[image]

### Safari

Please share a link to your screenshot; or edit this answer

## Conclusion

- https://github.com/fergald/docs/blob/master/explainers/css-shadow-parts-1.md
  Says: *"to style inside a shadow tree, from **outside** of that shadow tree."*
- Some AI that often gives inclomplete answers says:
  *"To summarize, the ::part pseudo-element is used to style elements within a Shadow DOM shadow tree that have a part attribute. It **does not style the shadow root itself**.*"

I can see use-cases for FireFox behavior, wonder what is used in the world already.

I use `::part` the Chrome way

Comment: Ah interesting. Maybe it's user error on my part for this feature. I had picked up somewhere in my research that it was preferable not to leverage classes when styling web-components. That's what set me on the path looking into `path`. But it seems like the actual intent is to allow the host page to style components inside a shadow root 

Comment: No user error on your part. Browsers behave different, thus its a bug. Unclear which Engine does it right at this point. For now I presume Safari will do it the Chromium way, and that is the intended behavior

Comment: I made it an issue: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/982